# unexpected argument 'key' found while generating keys

Tags: substrate-parachain-template

I want to generate keys for my parachain-template-node but using this command gives me error.

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav-parachain % ./target/release/parachain-template-node key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive
error: unexpected argument 'key' found

Usage: parachain-template-node [OPTIONS] [-- <RELAY_CHAIN_ARGS>...]
       parachain-template-node <COMMAND>

For more information, try '--help'.
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air xcav-parachain %
```

I use command from [here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/#generate-your-account-and-keys)

Is the command changed? Someone please help me.

Comment: run `./target/release/parachain-template-node --help` as it suggests

Comment: There should be something about `key` or `generate` on the help page

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial is not using `parachain-node-template`,it uses the `node-template`. In the node-template we have the `key` subcommand that is a CLI for key management but in parachain-node-template this feature is not available.

See the code for the [`node-template`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/cli.rs#L17):

```rs
pub enum Subcommand {
    /// Key management cli utilities
    #[command(subcommand)]
    Key(sc_cli::KeySubcommand),
```

And notice is different for the [`parachain-node-template`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/main/node/src/cli.rs#L5).

But there are several ways you can generate keys, you can use the standalone `subkey` command-line program. See here how to use it from the `polkadot-sdk` repository: [Subkey tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/)